# To what extent did the Chinese government force Catholic priests to marry?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, marriage, persecution, china

In his book *The Souls of China*, Ian Johnson writes about a type of religious persecution that was inflicted on some groups in China during the Cultural Revolution (1966–76):

> Across the country, Buddhist, Daoist, and Catholic clergy who had taken vows of chastity were forced to marry. ([page 26](https://books.google.com/books?id=E9dLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA26))

Sadly, Johnson doesn't provide any additional information about this, and a quick Google search didn't give me any clues either.  This situation raises a number of related questions.

- First of all, do we know approximately how many cases of this type of persecution were inflicted on Catholics?
- Second, how did the government put the "marriage" into effect?  Who officiated, and was it done in a church?
- Third, did the government actually attempt to enforce this "marriage"?  Did it require that the "married" people live together?  Did it somehow ensure that vows of chastity were broken?
- Fourth, would such involuntary "marriages," even if they were performed in accordance with government laws, considered invalid by the Church?  I assume so!

Put simply, to what extent (both quantitatively and qualitatively) did the Chinese government force Catholic clergy to "marry" during the Cultural Revolution?

Comment: A cardinal in an Eastern European country actually ordained married priests in order to put out a red herring during the height of the communist persecutions. After the persecutions were over Rome gave these priests three solution:  Serve the Church in the Roman Rite as deacons or remain a priest in a Eastern Rite of their choice or leave the active ministry all together.